# Google Analytics: install on static html

Tags: google-analytics

My question is same as the link :
[How to use Google Analytics to track views of static HTML pages on file server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894783/how-to-use-google-analytics-to-track-views-of-static-html-pages-on-file-server)

[image]

It requires me to input the website with the http and https, but my static file is using local path,
how can I input the website URL?

Also, I cant find the tracking info under the property, so please help and thanks for answering the questions!

Answer (score 0):

This URL is required but it is not decisive for the functioning and data collection in Google Analytics, so you can enter whatever you want to proceed with the setup.

You can find measurement ID by selecting the stream in Data stream.